# How to translate WP plugin name?

Tags: plugin-development, translation

My plugins are translated ready. I've created their pot, po and mo files in 2 languages for each one using **PoEdit Pro** and all of my plugins are loading the translation files correctly.
But there's a problem with all of them and it's the plugin's name and description. These 2 parts doesn't get translated at all. In all of my plugins.
I attach a screenshot to describe the area I'm talking about, more specifically.
In addition,
I've used _e() for translatable texts but title and description doesn't work with it. They accept __() instead.
I feel it's a minor task I need to do but have no idea what is it.
Could you teach me how to figure it out please?

Why WP tutorials available in the web doesn't cover translation enough? I've no idea!

[image: How to translate WP plugin's name and description?]

Comment: Those look like widgets not plugins, can you confirm this? Be as precise and specific as possible, even if you think it's obvious

Comment: Yes those are widgets. I meant extensions by "plugins". But they are widgets. This is more specific.

Comment: test to find if the translations are correctly called before the widget instantiation

Comment: I've done it. As I said it's being read completely. All of the widget is showing translated texts but only title and description are not changed.

Comment: Did you use language functions in the widget class constructor?

Comment: Yes, I did that too.

Comment: questions should include the code you are talking about. anyway from the answer your problem is obvious, you do not follow the 1000 tutorials around the web (sorry, but really hate when people use questions to rant)... text domain names should be constant, not variables.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find the right way but figured out this way:

```
if (get_locale() == 'fa_IR') {
            parent::__construct(
                'araccordion_widget',
                __('افزونه وردپرس', $text_domain),
                array( 'description' => __( 'توضیحات افزونه به زبان فارسی در اینجا نوشته میشود.', $text_domain ), )
            );
        }
        else {
            parent::__construct(
                'araccordion_widget',
                __('WordPress Widget', $text_domain),
                array( 'description' => __( 'The description in English, goes here', $text_domain ), )
            );
        }
```

It works though it doesn't seem the right way because if the widget is translated to more languages in the future, I've to add an elseif for it too. Otherwise the title and the desc will be still English in that new language.